# Query for static type in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

When I query for abstract types using Linq, it also grabs static classes.

```
IEnumerable<Type> FilterInheritable()
{
     var q = Assembly.Load("Assembly-CSharp").GetTypes()
       .Where(x => x.IsAbstract == true);            

     return q;
}
```

Is it possible to filter out the static types? Something like this?

```
IEnumerable<Type> FilterInheritable()
{
     var q = Assembly.Load("Assembly-CSharp").GetTypes()
       .Where(x => x.IsAbstract == true)
       .Where(x => x.IsStatic != true);

     return q;
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to compare a `bool` to `true`, the result of the comparison is `bool  again. So `x => x.IsAbstract` is the same as `x => x.IsAbstract == true`.

Answer (score 4):

Since `static` classes are also `sealed` by definition, but `abstract` classes cannot be `sealed`, you can do this:

```
var q = Assembly.Load("Assembly-CSharp").GetTypes()
                .Where(x => x.IsAbstract && x.IsClass && !x.IsSealed);
```

I added `IsClass` to exclude interfaces as well.